# Ubuntu 18.04 LTS Multiple Monitor Issue

Tags: multiple-monitors, display

This is my first time on this forum so I don't quite know how things work yet.

I recently had an idea to compare popular Linux distribution Ubuntu 18.04 LTS against Windows 10 and Hackintosh Mac OS X Mavericks for a Youtube video since Microsoft is apparently not releasing any more operating systems after Windows 10.

My issue is that I run dual monitors for multitasking while gaming and other applications. After switching to Ubuntu 18.04 LTS my second monitor was showing weird artifacting. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pYKNrGeCnVU the issue starts around 30 seconds in, but watching before reveals the monitor does in fact work.

I don't know if this is a bug with Ubuntu, but both monitors work just fine in Ubuntu on there own, but together my larger monitor doesn't work, I have tried running both monitors together on my discrete GPU, one on my CPU's iGPU and one on the GPU, and both on my CPU's iGPU and it doesn't work.